# Force a 404 on Web API routes (and sub endpoints)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm looking for a simple way to return a 404 error on all requests to a given route in Web API, and all endpoints in that route. In my scenario, I'll have a configuration flag to turn it on and off. It's a documentation endpoint using Swagger/Swashbuckle, and want the ability to turn it on and off as a feature toggle of sorts.

```
<add key="EnableDocumentation" value="true|false" />
```

Ideally, for all routes starting with /swagger (including /swagger/ui/index.html) I want to return a 404 if the above value is **false**

I tried IgnoreRoute in HttpConfiguration.Routes, but that doesn't work for routes deeper than the level specified. If I ignore /swagger, it's still possible to access /swagger/ui/index.html

Any suggestions on a good way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Something like that would have to come from Swagger/Swashbuckle. If the route exists, it's going to get returned. That's how servers work.  You would need to essentially disable the hook into the routes table for this plugin, so that nothing could ever be matched, which either means using some method they provide, or just disabling the entire machinery for it outright.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for the comment. Very interesting. Do you know if there is a way to define a /swagger route with higher priority, which would essentially do the same thing? Or would that just cause other issues? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, if this is in your RouteConfig, you can just add a route befire that one. Since routes are processed top-down, it will always catch first. Then you could just return a 404 from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by writing up your own **custom HTTP module**.

In your HTTP module you could check the incoming url request and return 404 if the url matches your route.

Check these out(only to get an idea of how a custom http module is written)

- [Writing your 1st HttpModule in ASP.NET under 2 minutes](http://yassershaikh.com/writing-your-1st-httpmodule-in-asp-net-under-2-minutes/)
- [An IP Address Blocking HttpModule for ASP.NET in 9 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AnIPAddressBlockingHttpModuleForASPNETIn9Minutes.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario whereby:

1. I want Swashbuckle installed for API documentation
2. I want to control access to Swagger without removing the Nuget Package or redeployment of the API

This led me to the following code:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    private const string AllowSwaggerUsageAppSetting = "AllowSwaggerAccess";

    public static void Register()
    {
        if (AllowSwaggerAccess)
        {
            Swashbuckle.Bootstrapper.Init(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        }

        // NOTE: If you want to customize the generated swagger or UI, use SwaggerSpecConfig and/or SwaggerUiConfig here ...
    }

    private static bool AllowSwaggerAccess
    {
        get
        {
            bool _parsedValue;

            return bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AllowSwaggerUsageAppSetting] ?? "false", out _parsedValue) && _parsedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless there is a key in the appSettings section of web.config with the name **AllowSwaggerAccess** and a **Bool.Parse**'able value of **true**, the Swashbuckle bootstrapper is ignored meaning swagger documentation cannot be accessed and requests to the API return a 404.

*The above code is based on v4 of the Swashbuckle Nuget Package.*

If you download the code from github you can see that the Init method is responsible for setting up the routes:

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Init(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "swagger_root",
            "swagger",
            null,
            null,
            new RedirectHandler("swagger/ui/index.html"));

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "swagger_ui",
            "swagger/ui/{*uiPath}",
            null,
            new { uiPath = @".+" },
            new SwaggerUiHandler());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "swagger_versioned_api_docs",
            "swagger/{apiVersion}/api-docs/{resourceName}",
            new { resourceName = RouteParameter.Optional },
            null,
            new SwaggerSpecHandler());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "swagger_api_docs",
            "swagger/api-docs/{resourceName}",
            new { resourceName = RouteParameter.Optional },
            null,
            new SwaggerSpecHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool. Something like this is exactly what I need. Given that Swashbuckle is enabled by default, would you need code to otherwise disable it? In your `if` statement, you're allowing it, but isn't it generally just enabled anyway? Hopefully I'm making sense!

Comment: You've confused me, ha!

Comment: Hah sorry! What I mean is: when you install Swashbuckle, it is automatically enabled at `/swagger`. But I don't see anywhere in your code that explicitly disables it. I only see code that would explicitly enable it, but isn't it already?

Comment: The 'Swashbuckle.Bootstrapper.Init(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);'line of code actually adds the route (amongst other things) - the if block prevents this from happening.

Comment: Makes sense. I will definitely have to give it a try!

Comment: I've added a snippet of the source as an example @trnelson